# Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.logging.LoggingManagerInternal'. Possible causes for this unexpected error

Tags: android, gradle

I want to publish my library on Bintray. I tried [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582) steps but gradle didn't sync.

`build.gradle` file of project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle` file of library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

and error like [that](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582)

```
20:10:03: Executing external task 'preBuild'...
        Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
        Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
            at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:606)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:572)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:569)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:568)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:565)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
            at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluationDependsOn(AbstractProject.java:578)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluationDependsOn(AbstractProject.java:570)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.ensureConfigured(DependencyManager.java:724)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencyForConfig(DependencyManager.java:240)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:139)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:356)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$9.call(VariantManager.java:597)
            at
    com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.java:51)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:593)      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:750)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$1.call(VariantManager.java:260)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:259)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$12.call(BasePlugin.java:657)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$12.call(BasePlugin.java:654)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:653)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:572)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:569)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:568)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:565)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
            at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:510)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:84)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:75)
            at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:143)
            at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
            at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * Where:
        Build file '/Users/emrekose/AndroidStudioProjects/MyLibraryApp/mylittlelibrary/build.gradle' line: 3

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating project ':mylittlelibrary'.
        > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven']
           > Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.

        * Try:
        Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

        * Exception is:
        org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':mylittlelibrary'.
            at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
            at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:144)
            at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:72)
            at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:149)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:510)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluationDependsOn(AbstractProject.java:578)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluationDependsOn(AbstractProject.java:570)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.ensureConfigured(DependencyManager.java:724)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencyForConfig(DependencyManager.java:240)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:139)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:356)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$9.call(VariantManager.java:597)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$9.call(VariantManager.java:594)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.java:51)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:593)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:750)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:459)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$1.call(VariantManager.java:263)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$1.call(VariantManager.java:260)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:259)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$12.call(BasePlugin.java:657)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$12.call(BasePlugin.java:654)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:653)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:572)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:569)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:568)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:565)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
            at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:510)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:84)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:75)
            at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:143)
            at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
            at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven']
            at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:160)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:35)
            at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)

            at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
            ... 113 more
        Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.
            ... 124 more
        Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.gradle.internal.logging.LoggingManagerInternal not present
            at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.instantiatePlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:59)
            ... 125 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.internal.logging.LoggingManagerInternal
            ... 128 more


        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 1.337 secs
        20:10:05: External task execution finished 'preBuild'.
```

Comment: What does building with `--stacktrace` say?

Comment: @JBirdVegas updated the post and i added --stacktrace logs

Comment: i solved this problem and i changed android-maven-gradle-plugin version 1.4.1 to 1.3 in `build.gradle` file of project.

Comment: @emrekose26 Thanks it worked. Reason mentioned  in the [issue](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/43) here

Comment: I fixed this by changing %project_dir%\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties 

to 

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

No downgrade necessary.

Answer (score 1):

May be its too late to answer here but i just want to share my solution for same.
what i did is removed build folder and gradle folder after that i did invalidate cache and restart android studio.

Bingo now its working cool. so ultimately no need to downgrade or upgrade your gradle version just follow this it will definitely help you.

Thanks